# Not seeing Win32 Console Application in Visual Studio 2015 after installing C++ components

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, console-application

I installed visual studio 2015 but with the "typical" setting instead of custom. It left me without C++ so I went ahead and downloaded the packages that were needed. This is what I see now: http://puu.sh/rDcmz/0627d54918.png

I see "Console Application" but I am looking for "Win32 console application". Unless these two are the same? But I think they aren't. Thanks.

Comment: You need to install the C++ tools, if you want to write C++ code. Your screenshot only shows C#.

Comment: That's strange. I followed this link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/07/24/setup-changes-in-visual-studio-2015-affecting-c-developers/ and check marked the 3 C++ options. I did this by going into Control panel > Visual Studio > Change > Modify> and applied those C++. Here again: http://puu.sh/rDecZ/357612ba01.png

Comment: I have installed those 3 check marked options and I still do not see C++ available whenever I go file>new project

Comment: Probably easiest to do a full reinstall.

Comment: @MicroVirus yeah, I did a full uninstall via control panel and selected C++ (all 3 choices) when installing custom. I can see win32 console application now.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling Visual Studio 2015 and then reinstalling seemed to have fixed the problem.